# use logstash filter ,aes gcm encrypted in ruby,but cannot decrypted in java

Tags: java, ruby, logstash, aes-gcm

ruby
class LogStash::Filters::Cipher < LogStash::Filters::Base
begin
data = event.get(@source)
if @mode == "encrypt"
@random_iv = OpenSSL::Random.random_bytes(@iv_random_length)
end
@cipher.iv = @random_iv
result = @cipher.update(data)+@cipher.final
if @mode == "encrypt"
if !@random_iv.nil?
result = @random_iv + result
end
if @algorithm.downcase.include? "gcm" or @algorithm.downcase.include? "ccm"
result = result + @cipher.auth_tag
@logger.info("Cipher auth_tag length: ", :auth_tag_length => @cipher.auth_tag.length)
@logger.info(' auth_tag '+Base64.strict_encode64(@cipher.auth_tag))
end
result =  Base64.strict_encode64(result).encode("utf-8") if @base64 == true
end
@logger.debug("Cipher algorithm: ", :algorithm => @algorithm)
rescue => e
# force a re-initialize on error to be safe
init_cipher

```
    else
      @total_cipher_uses += 1

      result = result.force_encoding("utf-8")
  end # def filter
  def init_cipher

    if !@cipher.nil?
      @cipher.reset
      @cipher = nil
    end
    @cipher = OpenSSL::Cipher::AES.new(128, :GCM)
    @total_cipher_uses = 0

    if @mode == "encrypt"
      @cipher.encrypt
    end

    if @key.length != @key_size
      @logger.debug("key length is " + @key.length.to_s + ", padding it to " + @key_size.to_s + " with '" + @key_pad.to_s + "'")
      @key = @key[0,@key_size].ljust(@key_size,@key_pad)
    end
    @cipher.key = @key
    @cipher.padding = @cipher_padding if @cipher_padding
    @cipher.padding=0
    if @algorithm.downcase.include? "gcm"
      @cipher.auth_data = @auth_data
      @logger.info("Cipher initialisation auth_data: ", :auth_data => @auth_data)
    end
  end # def init_cipher
end # class LogStash::Filters::Cipher
```

java:

```
    byte[] textBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(text);
    byte[] iv = new byte[16];
    ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.wrap(textBytes);
    bb.get(iv);
    byte[] cipherText = new byte[bb.remaining()];
    bb.get(cipherText);
    try {
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(mode);
        SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = getSecretKeySpec(key);
        GCMParameterSpec gcmParameterSpec=new GCMParameterSpec(128, textBytes,0,16);
        System.out.println(Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(gcmParameterSpec.getIV()));
        System.out.println(gcmParameterSpec.getTLen());
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec, gcmParameterSpec);
        cipher.updateAAD("".getBytes());
        byte[] decryptedBytes = cipher.doFinal(textBytes,16,textBytes.length-16);

        return new String(decryptedBytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

I have put `iv` and `auth_tag` in ciphertext, and split `iv` in java, but still tag mismatch.

I test it in nodejs, it works ok. The ciphertext that nodejs encrypt can be decrypted in java.

`new GCMParameterSpec(128, textBytes,0,16)` I tried to change to `new GCMParameterSpec(96, textBytes,0,16)`

Comment: GCM usually applies a 12 bytes IV, while the Java code uses 16 bytes, maybe that is the problem. But this is just a guess, as both codes are incomplete and especially the length of the IV is not clear from the Ruby code. Complete both codes so that they are executable(`@iv_random_length`, `@cipher`,..., `getSecretKeySpec()`,...), post non-productive test data, see [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @iv_random_length = 16, auth_tag length is 16 in ruby, I've compared iv data
and they're the same

Comment: You cannot use a 16 bytes IV with Ruby/OpenSSL without having explicitly defined this length in the Cipher instance beforehand. So either you are not using a 16 bytes IV or the posted code and the code you are running are different. Currently the problem is not reproducible for me (with uniform IV length). Edit your question, post sample data and OpenSSL version!